# Creating a static copy of a MoinMoin site

Tags: wget, moinmoin

I have a MoinMoin site which I've inherited from a previous system
administrator. I'd like to shut it down but keep a static copy of the
content as an archive, ideally with the same URLs. At the moment I'm
trying to accomplish this using wget with the following parameters:

```
--mirror
--convert-links
--page-requisites
--no-parent
-w 1
-e robots=off
-user-agent="Mozilla/5.0"
-4
```

This seems to work for getting the HTML and CSS, but it fails to
download any of the attachments. Is there an argument I can add to wget
which will get round this problem?

Alternatively, is there a way I can tell MoinMoin to link directly to
files in the HTML it produces? If I could do that then I think wget
would "just work" and download all the attachments. I'm not bothered
about the attachment URLs changing as they won't have been linked to
directly in other places (e.g. email archives).

The site is running MoinMoin 1.9.x.

My version of wget:

```
$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.16.1 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls +ntlm +opie -psl +ssl/openssl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the end was to use MoinMoin's export dump functionality:

https://moinmo.in/FeatureRequests/MoinExportDump

It doesn't preserve the file paths in the way that `wget` does, but has the major advantage of including all the files and the attachments.